# QGIS Import Fails with Invalid Data Source Error Loading LAS file: "Global encoding WKT flag not set for point format 6 - 10."

Tags: qgis, las, point-cloud

I am trying to import some .las files in QGIS 3.28. I am successful with other files but for one file when I drag the file and drop it in the QGIS interface, it produces the following error:

> Invalid Data Source: path/to/file.laz is not a valid or recognized data source, error: "readers.las: Global encoding WKT flag not set for point format 6 - 10."

I just want to observe the data, I don't care if it is not in the correct projection, etc.

Is there a way that I can skip this error in the QGIS Interface?

There is an answer for a Python library but that doesn't seem to be relevant in this case.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413191/python-pdal-error-reading-format-1-4-las-file-readers-las-error-global-enco

Comment: @DaveX that is not for QGIS, I have no idea how to do that in the GUI...

Comment: @Alrl DaveX sent the same link, it doesn't answer it.

Comment: Please post a "good" LAS and a "bad" LAS. (WeTransfer or DropBox, etc.)

Comment: The solution in the linked answer should work. Use the small python snippet to fix your file: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/428091/15183 . You can use that from the python console in QGIS. Just give the full file path and name as filename and make a backup of the original file before, just in case...