# Untwine error: Can't refer reader for a LAS file (Point Cloud File)

Tags: qgis, las, point-cloud

I was trying to import a las file to QGIS 3.28.12 Firenze. It really take me sometime to attempt to load the file but still failed to display all the points.

So I downloaded a point cloud file for a tile of area in Hong Kong (I uploaded the most original one here): https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkexiEOtl5b2hKko2SRYQ4LU20ylvA?e=RMgRgu

And when I dragged the file to QGIS canvas an error occured: (readers.las Error) Global encoding WKT flag not set for point format 6 - 10. I am sure many of you have encountered this error before and I found a solution here: [Python-PDAL: error reading Format 1.4 LAS File - (readers.las Error) Global encoding WKT flag not set for point format 6 - 10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413191/python-pdal-error-reading-format-1-4-las-file-readers-las-error-global-enco)

I follow the solution by opening the python console and copied the code in the link above and seemingly worked and modified the las file.

This time I drag the las file to QGIS canvas again and while the extent of tile in red dashed line box appeared, this time another error occured: Untwine error: Can't infer reader for [the file location]. Which is really frustrating!

https://1drv.ms/i/s!AkexiEOtl5b2hKkpivkxltf0orQTDg?e=VoAyFz

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the CRS for the Hong Kong data is problematic for PDAL (and PROJ). Luckily, I have already processed all of the HK data into EPT for my own use and put it online.

`https://na-c.entwine.io/hk-2020/ept.json`

If you add that URL as a remote data source in the Add Point Cloud panel, you should be able to view all of the HK data with a CRS that doesn't fail.

https://viewer.copc.io/?copc=https://na-c.entwine.io/hk-2020/ept.json

Comment: Oh wow great thanks! And I can access all the LAS data throughout Hong Kong without a need to download it from CEDD website! So you take quite a lot of time to download the data since each LAS file is very large?

Comment: No, I had a customer who needed it, I posted a tweet on Twitter back when that wasn't broken, and someone saw it and offered to go to the HK engineering office with a 16tb harddrive and ship it back to me :) https://x.com/howardbutler/status/1529516102853840898?s=20